# syntax highlight for TextEditor

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

is it possible to apply syntax highlight to Eclipse `TextEditor` (`org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor`)? i would like to show some XML code in it, and having it highlighted ... I googled but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You could find an Eclipse XML editor plug-in, or you can make your own XML editor by following the directions in this article:

[How to create an enhanced Eclipse XML editor using JFace Text](http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/jface-text.php)